# About related rates

Tags: calculus

One leg of a right triangle decreases at 1cm/min and the other leg increases at 2cm/min. At what rate is the area changing when the first leg is 8cm and the second leg is 6cm

Comment: Is it a right triangle?

Comment: more info is required

Comment: What have you tried?  Please show us your thoughts like $A = \frac12 \ell h$, $\ell'(t) = 2$, $h'(t) = -1$, $$A'(t) = \frac12 \frac{d}{dt} (\ell h) = \dots$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A = \frac 12 xy\\
x = 8, y = 6\\
A = 24$

$\frac {dA}{dt} = \frac 12 (y \frac{dx}{dt} + x\frac{dy}{dt})$

$\frac {dx}{dt}, \frac {dy}{dt}$ is given.

Answer (score 1):

$A = {1\over2}l_1l_2$

Therefore, $A' = {1\over2}(l_1'l_2 + l_2'l_1) = {1\over2}(-l_2 + 2l_1)$

When $l_1 =8$ and $l_2 = 6$, $A' = 5$

Answer (score 0):

Given : $L_1 = 8, L_1^\prime = -1$

$L_2 = 6, L_2^\prime = 2$

To find : $A^\prime$

---

$$2A = L_1L_2$$

$$2A^\prime = L_1^\prime L_2 + L_2^\prime L_1 = (-1)6 + (2)(8) = -6 + 16 = 10\  \mathrm{cm^2/s}$$

$$A^\prime = 5 \  \mathrm{cm^2/s}$$